# Deleting tokens from query in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm mapping the terms of a user query to some recognized numeric values, and I want remove unrecognized ones.

For example: `"Green apple pie for cats" => "[tag_1] [tag_2] [for] [tag_3]"` and I want to remove all of the values that match `tag_\d+` or anything equivalent..

Comment: some example ..

Comment: You could implement a custom analyzer that a custom stopwords list (if I understand what you are asking for). Another way is to simply do on the application level.